# After attach SP2010 content DB to SP2013, can I let the site in SP2010 mode forever?

Tags: upgrade

I need to migrate a SP2010 farm to SP2013. The old sites layout were customized to fit our company website style. After test migrate to sp2013, I found that all layout change to the default style.

By reading [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/branding-issues-that-may-occur-when-upgrading-to-sharepoint-2013-HA104052656.aspx), it seems I need to re-create a new Master page. I am not a designer. It seems impossible for me.

My question is, is it possible to make the ugpraded site stay in SP2010-mode forever? In this way Microsoft still support this sites? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not many people will pick this option (keep SP2010 mode on SP2013 farm for long time). One of reason not to do it because your search index will be messed up. In my test, I have setup a content source to crawl site collection A only but end up it crawl entire farm.

For details you can see my other thread:
[SP2013 - How to create a content sources for specific site collection?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101514/sp2013-how-to-create-a-content-sources-for-specific-site-collection)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MS has announced anything and not knowing what will go into the next version it would also be hard.

But based on history I'd not expect 2010 mode to be supported in the next version of SharePoint.

Could you the stay in 2010 mode until you want to upgrade to this next version (if ever)?
Yes, but if you expect to upgrade to this new version, then I'd rather perform the upgrade to 2013 UI before that, such that you aren't forced into doing a double upgrade at that point in time.

Also don't expect 2010 mode to be as well tested with Service Packs as 2013 mode.