# SP2013 - How to create a content sources for specific site collection?

Tags: search, content-source

I have tried research for hours and cannot find a tutorial to show me how to do it. Maybe because the question seems too simple. However I have tried mulitple times and keep doing wrong.

We have 4 site collections:

```
http://my.com/sites/A 

http://my.com/sites/B 

http://my.com/sites/C

http://my.com/sites/D
```

In the Search Service Application web interface, I created a new content sources "Site A" with source type "Web sites". I type in single entry "http://my.com/sites/A". Then I start a full crawl. By some reason, when I check crawl history, this content source crawl all 4 site collections A,B,C,D.

I have applied another approach. I created another new content sources with source type "Sharepoint", select "Only crawl the Site Collection of each start address", then type in single entry "http://my.com/sites/A". There is no different. It still crawl entire farm. (including items from A, B, C, D and people)

What is wrong with my setup? How can I check? Thanks!

Comment: Actually I just migrated SC A,B,C,D to SP2013 and promoted them in SP2013 evaluation mode. Do you think there is bug in this mode?

Comment: Can I ask, what are you trying to achieve? Do you need separate content sources or can you create separate result sources to achieve the same result?

Comment: I can create separate result source to achieve same result. But it will allow the site collection owners change the result source and search other SC contents.

Comment: Again, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make sure the searchbox in site A will not search out anything from B,C and D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually a bug when you crawl on a site collection in SP2013 evaluation mode. The SharePoint crawler have strange beheviour against these evaluating sites and mess their index altogether.

After I fully upgrade the evaluating site to SP2013, reset index, and setup the content sources again, everything works as expected. Thanks and sorry for my careless.

Answer (score 1):

The way search works in SharePoint is to security trim the results before showing the results to a users. Generally you will set up a content source of http://my.com (for the example you provided).

If you don't want users to see what is in other site collections use security on the sites. They will not see results from Sites that they cannot access.

If you configure search at the site level they can "Search this site" initially and if you like search from a central search center.